# Ubuntu allow same/one/single user to connect from specific/many/multiple IP's?

Tags: ssh

What is the correct syntax for telling SHH to allow user MyUser login from IP_1 and IP_2? Because I have this config in my ssh_config:

```
AllowUsers MyUser@IP_1
AllowUsers MyUser@IP_2
```

and I only have access from IP_2 but not IP_1. I checked IP_1 and it matches so I am thinking that there is supposed to be a different syntax to have it how I want.

**UPDATE:** I have changed ssh allow users to look like:

```
AllowUsers MyUser@IP_2 MyUser@IP_1 MyUser@IP_3[thi is EOF - no new line after this]
```

But nothing changed: I still can connect from IP_2 but not IP_1. I have also added other IP which I can not test at the moment. After changing sshd_config I ran `sudo service ssh restart` and even tried `sudo service ssh reload`. Only other non defaulf config of sshd_config is that I have disabled remote root user login.

In the auth.log it says:

```
Failed password for invalid user MyUser from IP_1 port 49622 ssh2
```

**UPDATE 2 - MISTERY SOLVED:** There was a typo in my connection config on the IP_1 machine's putty username value for the remote server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the information all on one line

```
AllowUsers MyUser@IP_1 MyUser@IP_2
```

Or specify a range

```
AllowUsers MyUser@1.2.3.*
```

Or some variation on the iprange 1.*.*.* etc

See the man page for details http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man5/sshd_config.5.html

> AllowUsers
>
> **This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns,
>   separated by spaces.**  If specified, login is allowed only for
>   user names that match one of the patterns.  Only user names are
>   valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized.  By default, login
>   is allowed for all users.  If the pattern takes the form
>   USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting
>   logins to particular users from particular hosts.  HOST criteria
>   may additionally contain addresses to match in CIDR
>   address/masklen format.  The allow/deny directives are processed
>   in the following order: DenyUsers, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, and
>   finally AllowGroups.

Restart the ssh server or reload the configuration after editing

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: You will have to update your question with details. Post your config file and the ssh command you ran with -vvv option - use pastebin for long output.

Comment: Found the typo error. It is a pretty long username in my defense!

Comment: No worries, that is why we use tab completion and copy-paste and also why we ask for the exact commands and config files rather than $some_user , so we can confirm the syntax and exclude typos. ;p